# How to sum up different currencies in Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, database-design, currency

I am currently building a Ruby on Rails invoicing application that is multilingual and supports a range of currencies. In the `dashboard` view all `invoices` a `user` has produced are totalled.

Now it would be nice if a user could choose the `currency` for each invoice.

But how can those invoices be totalled if *different* currencies are used?

E.g. if these three invoices were created today:

- Invoice No. 1: $1000.00
- Invoice No. 2: $2000.00
- Invoice No. 3: €1000.00

---

- **Total: $4333.60**

### ----------------------

The dollar-euro exchange rate would have to be based on each invoice's `date` of course.

How can this be achieved in Rails and does it even make sense?

Thanks for any pointers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of of multiple invoices using different currencies is not a single number, it's a collection of numbers. If you have a 20 USD invoice, a 15 EUR invoice, and a 20 EUR invoice, the sum is "20 USD + 35 EUR".

At the time when a payment is made from a single account using a single base currency, then a conversion will be performed to determine how much will have to be paid in that currency to cover the total converted costs. Presumably, there will also be currency conversion fees added at that time.

Answer (score 2):

It would be convenient if you change the currency to a single one, either euro or dollar right when the user makes an invoice. That is, you save the 'converted' value in your database. In this way you won't have to lookup for past day rates.

[Eu_central_bank](https://github.com/RubyMoney/eu_central_bank) provides exchange rates.